# How to read lines from text file that does not contain a specific value?

Tags: python

I want to read all lines in `filename` but whatever is in `searchparam1`, I don't want it to be read. This is my code, but I keep getting an error:

```
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print("Content-Type: text/html\n")    # HTML is following

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
fileID = form.getvalue("filename")
searchParam1= form.getvalue("search1")
searchParam2 = form.getvalue("search2")

fileArray = []

with open(fileID, "r") as targetfile:
    fileArray = targetfile.readlines()

for line in targetfile:              
    if re.search(str(searchParam1).lower(), line.lower()) == None:
        print ("ok")


for i in range(0,len(fileArray)):
    print(fileArray[i])
    print("<br/>")
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: error is in "for line in targetfile"

it says 

line undefined, targetfile = <_io.TextIOWrapper name='filename.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

Comment: Please explain your issue and add some details.

Comment: sorry i had some typos in my post, just correct it, can you have a look again please ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is an indentation issue. You can access 'targetfile' only inside `with`

```
with open(fileID, "r") as targetfile:
    fileArray = targetfile.readlines()

    for line in targetfile:              
        if re.search(str(searchParam1).lower(), line.lower()) == None:
            print ("ok")
```

Comment: indentation issue ? what do you mean exactly ? thank you.

Comment: Check the snippet above.

Comment: ah right, i corrected it, but now it gives me a server error instead